# live555 Server streaming x264 not working, how to debug?

Tags: vlc, live555, ffserver

Before diving into the SDK Version, i simply tried to stream an x264 encdoed video to VLC. Streaming MP3 Works, but x264 takes a while then i get an error, that vlc cannot open the file.

1) Downloaded Live555 Server

2) Started EXE which states the url to use as: `rtsp://172.18.1.85/<filename>`

3) In VLC i am using: `rtsp://172.18.1.85/fantastic.264`  As the server output says "Each files type is inferred from it's name suffix" so i renamed the file from `fantastic.mp4` to `fantastic.264`

As i've stated an mp3 stream works fine in the same directory where fantastic.264 is placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file ending was correct but it wasn't an "elementary h264 stream". So I had to reconvert it to an elementary h264 file.

Quick Fix:

```
ffmpeg -i fantastic.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -f h264 fantastic.264
```

You can get here more Information:
[What does Elementary Stream mean in Terms of H264](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090114/what-does-elementary-stream-mean-in-terms-of-h264/27091535?noredirect=1#comment42710610_27091535)